# What counts as a foot fault when serving and when attacking from the back court?

Tags: rules, officiating, volleyball

In volleyball, what exactly is considered a foot fault when
a) serving?
b) attacking from the back court part (i.e. by a player from the back row)?

Three possible options come to mind:
* players are not allowed to even touch the line.
* players are allowed to touch the line but cannot cross it.
* players can cross the line, but only partially (i.e. with just a part of their 
feet) - just as the case is at the central line with regular attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first option is correct. [FIVB Official Volleyball Rules 2013–2016](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/RulesOfTheGame_VB.asp), article 12.4.3:

> At the moment of the service hit or take-off for a jump service, the server must not touch the court (the end line included) or the floor outside the service zone.
>   After the hit, he/she may step or land outside the service zone, or inside the court.

Note that in beach volleyball, there is an additional statement that the server’s foot may not even go *under* the end line.

Comment: Is this true not only for serving but also for attacking by players from the back row?

Comment: Indeed. “13.2.2.1 at his/her take-off, the player's foot (feet) must neither have touched nor crossed over the attack line“ (and “after his/her hit, the player may land within the front zone”).